# SAVED QUERIES ARE HIDDEN

Tags: google-bigquery

My SAVED QUERIES section is hidden somewhere on bigquery that I could not find it. Still be able to save new queries but I could not find them afterwards. Do you guys know how to fix it? Thanks a lot!!! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6q4E.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I've got this message in the UI:

> We've moved all saved queries (personal, project, and public) into the
> Explorer for easier access. Expand projects to access saved queries.

[image]

Comment: I don't see it in the Explorer too :( do you know how to expand projects to access saved queries?

Comment: ahhhhhhh I found it! Thanks a lot!!!!!! :D :D :D